# How to handle multiple parent types with JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I've inherited a system which has several tables of a form like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Notes (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    note TEXT,
    parent_id INT,
    parent_type VARCHAR
);
```

Basically, the idea is that you could have several other types, say "Tickets" and "Widgets", and if you want to add a note for ticket 123, you'd do:

```
INSERT INTO Notes (note, parent_id, parent_type)
    VALUES ('blah blah', 123, 'ticket');
```

Is there any sensible way to have JPA create `@OneToMany` relationships from, say, a Ticket to a Note with this schema?

Or would I need to split my Notes table out into separate Ticket_Notes, Widgets_notes, etc tables?

Would it be possible to create separate TicketNotes, WidgetNotes, etc entities in Java using `@DiscriminatorColumn`, perhaps?

Comment: why not define the classes? and then attempt to match up to tables ... would make it far easier to visualise. No need to have join tables if you're using "parent_id" as the FK to the 1-N owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that taking advantage of discriminators and inheritance gets me what I want.

For example:

```
@Entity
class Ticket {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ticket", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TicketNotes> notes;
}


@Entity
@Inheritence
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PARENT_TYPE")
public abstract class Note {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    // ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ticket")
public class TicketNote extends Note {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Ticket ticket;
}
```

Helpful reference: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: You should probably define Notes as @MappedSuperclass because Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the entities that inherit from it. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

Comment: @MappedSuperclass seems like it's for a different sort of inheritance than I'm using here (SINGLE_TABLE): http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Single_Table_Inheritance vs http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Mapped_Superclasses -- in my case, I do only have a single table, so I think I'm going to stick with the pattern used above.